# mod_rewrite change original URI

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite

Using mod_rewrite (and CakePHP):

```
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*)  /combine?type=javascript&files=$1 [PT,L]
```

I want to change

http://bla.com/javascript/flyout.ribbon.js,jquery.min.js

to

http://bla.com/combine?type=javascript&files=flyout.ribbon.js,jquery.min.js

The problem is CakePHP looks at the original URL (inside parseParams() below) http://bla.com/javascript/ and decides that I want to access **JavascriptController** /javascript instead of **CombineController** /combine  inside Dispatcher.php

```
public function dispatch(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response, $additionalParams = array()) {
    if ($this->asset($request->url, $response) || $this->cached($request->here)) {
        return;
    }

    Router::setRequestInfo($request);
    $request = $this->parseParams($request, $additionalParams);
 .....
}

public function parseParams(CakeRequest $request, $additionalParams = array()) {
    if (count(Router::$routes) == 0) {
        $namedExpressions = Router::getNamedExpressions();
        extract($namedExpressions);
        $this->_loadRoutes();
    }

    $params = Router::parse($request->url);
    $request->addParams($params);
.....
}
```

Is there any way I can modify the original URL using mod_rewrite ? (or am i just misunderstanding things)

Comment: i think this can be achieved in routes php, in the config folder. there you can put how to parse the parameters/pages... this is a way around for your problem since i don't know how to mess up with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Modified routes.php by adding the following:

```
Router::connect('/javascript/:filenames/*', 
                array('controller' => 'combine', 'action' => 'combineJs'), 
                array('pass' => array('filenames')));
```